# Media download/upload in S3 + Cloudfront

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, video.js

I've got a frontend built with angularJS that speaks to a backend in Java.

I have all code up and running which uploads and downloads images from S3 to my app.

I can also access videos in S3 and display them with the videojs library.

Performance-wise, I've been reading a bit about Amazon Cloudfront. I've already implemented the ETag cache in my code and it works well.

However, what is my next step to integrate this Cloudfront? All tutorials I've looked into only show static files. Would I need to make additional code changes or is it only a matter of configuration on my AWS stack? One of the key points I want to achieve and learn is how to make the videos being streamed instead of having them downloaded fully into the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CloudFront** is a **Content Delivery Network (CDN)**. You create a distribution and you tell it which S3 bucket holds the files you want to serve. Then, if you have a domain name you can add a CNAME cdn.yourdomain.com and map it to the domain offered to you by CloudFront.

Users visiting c**dn.yourdomain.com/yourfile** will effectively get the cached versions instead of downloading them from S3.

You can also create an RMTP distribution for streaming, which allows users to play the video while it's being downloaded and it uses the Adobe Flash Media RMTP protocol but, be cautious: as reported [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=7356), **CloudFront is discontinuing support for RTMP distributions on December 31, 2020.**

Comment: So there is no coupling needed between the ETag that my app returns and CDN? I thought I needed to make additional changes but I might've looked in the wrong places

Comment: With CloudFront, you can simply point your client to the cdn domain name and it will serve the content from the closest server to the incoming request. CloudFront already "caches" your content by storing it to the closest server to the incoming request. This depends also on how you have decided to distribute your content when creating the distribution. If you have chosen "All regions" no matter where the request comes from the content delivery will be fast